# (MySQL) Result become 0 when using full where conditions but the value result appear is true when I put single condtion

Tags: mysql

I tried to join 5 table and determine it by last position.

This is the matrix.

[image: Matrix]

I did, but the thing is I should select all fields on all join tables to help making a comparation, after that I add case when to determine the last position. This is the result I got.

[image: Result]

When I put the `count()`, and add single where condition the result appear as same as what it is.

This is the result ( Sampling )

[image: Sampling]

But when I tried to count it with all conditions the result become 0.
It didn't same as what I wanted at matrix above ( Output ).

[image: Output]

My question are:

1. It's possible to simplyfiy the script, without any select column as helper, just select ( Reject, Cair, Pending, InProcess ) ?
2. When I put all where conditions why it become 0, beside when I put single condition the result appear as same as what it is.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
a.id_cabang DTBO, b.id_cabang REJECT, c.id_cabang CAIR, d.id_cabang PENDING, e.id_cabang INPROSES,
count( CASE WHEN 
    b.id_cabang
    IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.id_cabang END ) AS reject
, 
count( CASE WHEN
    b.id_cabang
    IS NULL THEN c.id_cabang ELSE 0 END) AS cair
, 
count( CASE WHEN
    c.id_cabang
    IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE d.id_cabang END) AS pending
, 
count( CASE WHEN
    b.id_cabang IS  NULL 
    AND 
    c.id_cabang IS  NULL 
    AND 
    d.id_cabang IS  NULL
    THEN e.id_cabang ELSE 0 END) AS inproses
FROM dtbo_tbl AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT id_cabang FROM reject_tbl 
) AS b
ON a.id_cabang = b.id_cabang
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT id_cabang FROM cair_tbl 
) AS c
ON a.id_cabang = c.id_cabang
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id_cabang FROM pending_tbl
) AS d
ON a.id_cabang = d.id_cabang
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id_cabang FROM inproses_tbl
) AS e
ON a.id_cabang = e.id_cabang
WHERE 
( CASE WHEN 
    b.id_cabang
    IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.id_cabang END ) > 0
AND
( CASE WHEN
    b.id_cabang
    IS NULL THEN c.id_cabang ELSE 0 END) > 0
AND
( CASE WHEN
    c.id_cabang
    IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE d.id_cabang END) > 0
AND
( CASE WHEN
    b.id_cabang IS  NULL 
    AND 
    c.id_cabang IS  NULL 
    AND 
    d.id_cabang IS  NULL
THEN e.id_cabang ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer.

```
SELECT 
 a.id_cabang DTBO, b.id_cabang REJECT, c.id_cabang CAIR, d.id_cabang PENDING,e.id_cabang INPROSES,
 COUNT( CASE WHEN b.id_cabang IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE b.id_cabang END ) AS reject, 
 COUNT( CASE WHEN b.id_cabang IS NULL THEN c.id_cabang ELSE NULL END) AS cair, 
 COUNT( CASE WHEN c.id_cabang IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE d.id_cabang END) AS pending, 
 COUNT( CASE WHEN b.id_cabang IS  NULL AND c.id_cabang IS NULL AND d.id_cabang IS NULL THEN e.id_cabang ELSE NULL END) AS inproses 
FROM dtbo_tbl AS a 
 LEFT JOIN 
 (
  SELECT id_cabang FROM reject_tbl 
 ) AS b
 ON a.id_cabang = b.id_cabang
 LEFT JOIN 
 (
  SELECT id_cabang FROM cair_tbl 
 ) AS c
 ON a.id_cabang = c.id_cabang
 LEFT JOIN
 (
  SELECT id_cabang FROM pending_tbl
 ) AS d
 ON a.id_cabang = d.id_cabang
 LEFT JOIN
 (
  SELECT id_cabang FROM inproses_tbl
 ) AS e
 ON a.id_cabang = e.id_cabang
 WHERE 
 ( CASE WHEN b.id_cabang IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE b.id_cabang END ) > 0
 OR
 ( CASE WHEN b.id_cabang IS NULL THEN c.id_cabang ELSE NULL END) > 0
 OR
 ( CASE WHEN c.id_cabang IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE d.id_cabang END) > 0
 OR
 ( CASE WHEN b.id_cabang IS NULL AND c.id_cabang IS  NULL 
             AND d.id_cabang IS NULL THEN e.id_cabang ELSE NULL END) > 0
```